# istio-sidecar-injector unknown authority x509

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio

We've been following the [guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection.html#automatic-sidecar-injection) for automatic sidecar injection in istio-0.5.0 on kubernetes 1.9.2, but have so far been unsuccessful due to certificate issues on the api-server.

When pods are created, the webhook is called, but the api-server rejects the certficate presented by istio-sidecar-injector/inject, stating:

```
W0205 09:15:27.389473       1 admission.go:257] Failed calling webhook, failing open sidecar-injector.istio.io: failed calling admission webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
E0205 09:15:27.389501       1 admission.go:258] failed calling admission webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Our API server has been configured with the following flags:

```
- --allow-privileged=true
- --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/admin.pem
- --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/admin-key.pem
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
- --tls-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.pem
- --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver-server.pem
- --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver-server-key.pem
- --secure-port=6443
- --enable-bootstrap-token-auth 
- --storage-backend=etcd3
- --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16
- --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
- --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.pem
- --insecure-port=8080
- --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
- --admissioncontrol=MutatingAdmissionWebhook,Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota,DefaultTolerationSeconds    
- --authorization-mode=RBAC
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://sts.windows.net/[...removed...]/
- --oidc-client-id=spn:[...removed...]
- --oidc-username-claim=upn
- --oidc-groups-claim=groups
- --v=0
- --advertise-address=10.1.1.200
- --etcd-servers=http://etcd-0:2379,http://etcd-1:2379,http://etcd-2:2379
```

The certificate has been signed by the ca.pem file, which we have given to the api-server via the --tls-ca-file flag, but still no cigar.
Any ideas out there on how we can get the kubernetes API admission controller to trust the certificate presented by the sidecar-injector?